# How can I change a video's src to a blob, the angularjs way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video, webrtc

I have an angularjs setup, like:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <span>{{config.localvideo}}</span>
     <video id="video" autoplay>    </video>
     <button ng-click="click()">Start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript file:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$window){
 $scope.config = {localvideo:""} ;
  $scope.click = function(){
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia( {video:true},function (stream) {
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.src = $window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    $scope.config = {localvideo: video.src};
        $scope.$apply();
    },function (error) {
    console.log(error); 
    });
 }
});
```

This works as intended: when the page loads, the video is just a black rectangle. When I click the button, I have to give camera permission, then the video shows the camera. The span shows the blob url, just so I can see it happen.

However, this is not the angularjs way, as I understand it. I shouldn't have to use document.getElementById or anything like it, I should be changing the object in $scope, and html elements should be updating through the Angular magic of ng-src.
Javascript I thought should work:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$window){
 $scope.config = {localvideo:""} ;
  $scope.click = function(){
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia( {video:true},function (stream) {
        $scope.config = {localvideo: $window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)};
        $scope.$apply();
    },function (error) {
    console.log(error); 
    });
 }
});
```

If I use this, adding an attribute to my video tag: ng-src="config.localvideo" , I would expect the $scope.config to change, the ng-src to pick that up, and the video to start playing. This does not happen. The span does update on button click, however, so it seems that $scope.config is being updated correctly. Can anyone explain what's going on, or not going on?

Thanks for any help.
Note: I'm using the chrome version of getUserMedia directly, not a shim, just for brevity and sanity checking at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it the "Angular Way" you need to write your own directive. It is safe to access the DOM in a directive because they have a `link` function which you can think of as a sort of `document.ready` for this specific element. In a link function, you know that Angular is done creating the DOM. Instead of using getElementById, the "element" passed into the link function below will be whatever you apply this directive to.

```
.directive("myStream", function(){
   return {        
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:{config:'='},
      link: function(scope, element, attributes){
       //Element is whatever element this "directive" is on
       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia( {video:true},function (stream) {
         element.src = $window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
         scope.config = {localvideo: element.src};
         scope.$apply(); //sometimes this can be unsafe.
       });
      }
   }

}
```

Now on your video item you just add "my-stream" as an attribute and pass it config="config".

```
<video my-stream config="config" /> {{config.localVideo}}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm still a little confused. It looks to me like this avoids the functionality I was looking for: press a button, change the video's source. If I want to do that, I would still have to write a function somewhere outside of this directive? Or should I define a function inside the directive, calling that from outside?

Comment: The problem is that Angular doesn't know about the webkitGetuserMedia function. So automatic binding won't happen without a directive to interpret the DOM. If the source were coming from anywhere else but a callback function, it would work like you expect. If you want a button to trigger this behaviour, the easiest way will be an event. From your parent controller `$scope.click = function(){ $scope.$broadcast('getUserMedia'); };` then inside your directive you'd do `$scope.$on('getUserMedia', function(){ //navigaotr code });` and that's where you'd put the handler.

Comment: There are several other ways to do it besides `$broadcast`, like watching a variable. But $broadcast is probably the easiest. You could also make the button part of your directive. Directives can have templates which contain more HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these clarifications!